# What are the arguments that are within the parenthesis of the controller actions below?

Tags: php, laravel

Working on a todo app tutorial, I don't quite understand what the argument `(Request $request)` means as well as other `(Task $task)` and so on.

I've done some research and I get answers about dependency injection and how this syntax came from Perl.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use App\Task;

class TasksController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        return view('welcome',compact('user'));
    }

    public function add()
    {
        return view('add');
    }

    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $task = new Task();
        $task->description = $request->description;
        $task->user_id = Auth::id();
        $task->save();
        return redirect('/'); 
    }

    public function edit(Task $task)
    {

        if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->id == $task->user_id)
        {            
                return view('edit', compact('task'));
        }           
        else {
             return redirect('/');
         }              
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Task $task)
    {
        if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
            $task->delete();
            return redirect('/');
        }
        else
        {
            $task->description = $request->description;
            $task->save();
            return redirect('/'); 
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: The Request and Task are arguments' class type. Meaning the argument passed to the method, when is called, has to be an instance of the same class as defined in the method declaration otherwise PHP through fatal error. Are you clear about this?

Comment: @NMoeini When you say class type, do you mean the name of the class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to understand what are the classes and how objects of a class created. Secondly, in object oriented programing everything we treat as an object. One single task is an object of Task class. So to edit a task we need to pass a task object.

On the other hand Request is a helper class for http, which allows you to get all the data carried out from previous http request. For example if your are submitting a form, all the form data as well as some extra data will be passed to the Laravel framework and we can access those data via Request class. You are right these all about dependency injection.

Further more, in object oriented programming world, the concept of dependency injection and objects are same. When you explore other object oriented programmings, you will find out your answer. Task is our class and we want to edit a task, so task must be an object of the class "Task" in OOP world of entity and data.

TO be clear, just remember what we used to do with procedural non object oriented programming. Simple, we used to do something like this

```
public function edit($task_id){ 
    //edit record (task) based on task id in mysql DB
}
```

But in OOP (object oriented Programming), we play with class and object not array and fields because we have ORM (object Relational Mappings).

**In very basic sense:**
if you want to write a method to add two int in c programming, you do like

```
sum(int a, int b){
    return a+b;
}
```

in this method you are passing two arguments to the method. but in your `edit` method above, you need to pass task object because your are working with data type task (simple word).

Comment: Thanks!! Coming from Rails and wasn't sure what the arguments meant!

Comment: Oh thats cool, arguments are parameters that we pass to our methods but now modern frameworks made our job easy and everything Object oriented.

Answer (score 0):

It is called type declaration in PHP also known as type hint in PHP 5. According to [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration)

> Type declarations allow functions to require that parameters are of a
>   certain type at call time. If the given value is of the incorrect
>   type, then an error is generated: in PHP 5, this will be a recoverable
>   fatal error, while PHP 7 will throw a Type Error exception.